# Don't move other content CSS

Tags: css, html

I have a div, it needs to have position:relative;. I want that div to not push other content out of the way, so bascially I want the content in the same places as if the div wasn't there, without having to use position:absolute;. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Post `css` and `html` or make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/H6zVW/3/
So basically the image isn't supposed to move the text at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
img {
  position: absolute;
}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H6zVW/4/)

Comment: Well, I guess I have misunderstood position:absolute;. This did exactly what I needed. Thanks.